# KeyError: 0 ; Python removing columns from a list

Tags: python

I have a function I wrote to remove columns from a 2D list (uploaded from a CSV):

```
#method to remove a column from a list if it does not contain an int
def remove_nonint(list):
    for row in list:
        for i in range(0, len(row)):
            if isinstance(row[i], ( int, long ) ) != True:  
                del row[i]
```

However, when I run this on the list, I get the following error:

```
<ipython-input-23-10a39a11efb3> in remove_nonint(list)
      3     for row in list:
      4         for i in range(0, len(row)):
----> 5             if isinstance(row[i], ( int, long ) ) != True:
      6                 del row[i]

KeyError: 0
```

list[0] looks like this:

```
{u'2B': 0,
 u'3B': 0,
 u'AB': 4,
 u'BB': 0,
 u'CS': 0,
 u'G': 1,
 u'GIDP': None,
 u'H': 0,
 u'HBP': None,
 u'HR': 0,
 u'IBB': None,
 u'R': 0,
 u'RBI': 0,
 u'SB': 0,
 u'SF': None,
 u'SH': None,
 u'SO': 0,
 u'lgID': u'NA',
 u'playerID': u'abercda01',
 u'stint': u'1',
 u'teamID': u'TRO',
 u'yearID': u'1871'}
```

EDIT: This is how I uploaded the CSV:

```
import unicodecsv

with open('lahman-csv_2015-01-24/batting.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f)
    batting = list(reader)

batting[0]
```

Comment: Is it a 2d list or a list of dicts?

Comment: maybe what you want is to change `for i in range(0, len(row)):` to `for key in row:`?

Comment: I used DictReader, so I suppose it is a list of dictionaries

Comment: Probably not a good idea to name your variables after python built-in types, e.g., `list`...

Answer (score 5):

`row` is a dict, not a list, so it does not necessarily have anything at index 0. In this case, as you see, it does not.

The usual way to iterate over a dict is either

`for key in some_dict:`
or
`for key, val in some_dict.items():`
The latter form is useful if you expect to be examining the value stored at `key`, and you want to give it a name rather than referring to some_dict[val], which can be cumbersome.

in this case, I would do something like this:

```
for row in list:
    for key, val in row.items():
        if not isinstance(val, ( int, long ) ):
             del row[key]
```

Comment: yea, I'm getting this error: ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: with python2, use `iteritems()` instead of `items()`

Comment: Yes, you can user iteritems if you like.

Comment: I thought that the ValueError was caused by items() in python2. But I mixed it up. It's iteritems that doesn't work in python3. The error must be because of something else.

Comment: @HåkenLid The ValueError was caused by a typo (since corrected) in my original answer. (I'd had `for key, val in row`, which is obviously incorrect)

Comment: If you use `iteritems` you get an error due to deleting from a dict whilst iterating over it. It seems like `items` saves you from this by returning a list of tuple pairs of key and value. The other way to resolve it is to make a copy of the dict before calling `iteritems`. So either way you don't escape the copy requirement. Probably `items` is more lightweight than a full copy, but I didn't measure it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have a list of dicts, you can use the following.

```
def remove_nonint(lst):
    for row in lst:
        for k, v in dict(row).iteritems():
            if not isinstance(v, (int, long)):  
                del row[k]
```

Which makes a copy of each `dict` to avoid the `changed size during iteration` error.

The alternative is to return a new list, with only the integer entries

```
def filter_nonint(lst):
    l = []
    d = {}
    for row in lst:
        for k, v in row.iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, (int, long)):  
                d[k] = v
        l.append(d)
    return l
```

or as a one-liner

```
def filter_nonint2(lst):
    return [{k: v for k, v in row.iteritems() if isinstance(v, (int, long))} for row in lst]
```

Comment: this is only returning the non-int columns

Comment: opposite of what I wanted

Comment: Ok should be good. As an aside `if isinstance(row[i], ( int, long ) ) != True:` is quite confusing code. Using `not` or `== False` to my eyes is easier to comprehend.